# Running Crusader Kings II with wine, some textures are wrong

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm using wine to run Crusader Kings II, and it works pretty much perfectly, except that some of the countries on the map are the wrong color. The most prominent example is France, which is a dark grey instead of the appropriate blue. In the console while the game is running I keep seeing this:

```
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
```

I have basically no experience with wine, and can't find an explanation online of what that means. When I first set it up, I had to run

```
winetricks d3dx9_36 dotnet20
```

to make it work in the first place, but after that I can run it with just `wine CK2game.exe`

I know this isn't a super huge problem, but it's one of those subtle annoyances that just grows and infuriates you. If there's any pointers you can give me I'd be really grateful.

Comment: This game is available natively through Steam.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Wine.  From https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu:

If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
```

Update packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install (example for the development branch):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

If you prefer to use the Staging branch, replace winehq-devel with winehq-staging in the line above.

The version of Wine in the Ubuntu repos is still 1.6, while the latest version is 1.9. It is very likely that the problem has been fixed in Wine already.

Comment: If this answer fixed you problem, please select the checkmark to mark the answer as the solution.  Thanks!